# ¿Por qué mis apk de Dotnet MAUI son tan pesadas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

Cuando creo una aplicación nueva de MAUI en Visual Studio y sin más la publico, la apk pesa mas de 110 MB. ¿Es normal?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo hice la prueba con MAU Blazor compilado para Android y el paquete aab pesa 29.6 MB

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes, lee las reglas por favor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. 2. Lectura recomendada para que edites la pregunta, evites negativos y aumentes las chances de obtener respuestas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822  Saludos.

Comment: Yussef gracias por responder, no se que debo estar haciendo mal yo entonces, porque acabo de probar con MAUI Blazor y me pesa lo mismo, 118mb... reviso a ver.... gracias

Comment: Esto toca preguntarlo indicando versiones de cosas que se están usando y estructura del proyecto que se está compilando.

Answer (score 0):

Es raro, cuando creo mi .APK me queda de 35MB (es una agenda), para genera el .APK realizo este proceso:

https://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/2023/05/generar-archivo-apk-en-maui.html

Comment: Hola. Procura que las respuestas sean autocontenidas. Si puedes indicar en la pregunta los pasos principales del procedimiento que sugieres, es mejor. Si ese blog desaparece, lo cierran, cancelan el usuario que lo creó... la respuesta deja de servirle a otros usuarios. Trata de evitar respuestas que sean sólo un enlace